# Is there a way to ignore indentation when calculating line length?

Tags: javascript, eslint

I'm using ESLint, and while I want to enforce a maximum line length, I want to ignore any indentation at the start of the line.

I've checked the docs and there doesn't seem to be any way to do this when indenting using spaces. If I was using tabs then I could set `{"tabWidth": 0}` but for spaces there doesn't seem to be an option like this.

Is there any way to ignore space indentation at the start of a line when using `"max-len"`?

Comment: I don't think there will be, because line length includes all characters on line. What's the point then to have 1000 spaces and then code?

Comment: @Justinas That's true, I probably misunderstood the intent of having a maximum line length. I thought it was to limit the amount of code on one line, but maybe it's actually to keep me from needing a horizontal scroll.

Comment: Yes, to keep your lines readable. This 80/120 symbols limit comes from old terminals where it was max to show before breaking line